# How to pay rent using a credit card?

Tags: canada, credit-card, rent

I am currently paying rent using personal cheques. Is there a way to route the payments through my credit card so that I get the travel points associated with the credit card?

I will pay off the credit card immediately with funds from my bank account.

Comment: If you can get "cash advances" on your credit card that might be an option.  Double check that the rewards program applies to them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How you can pay your rent is really up to your landlord.

They are, however, unlikely to take a credit card, for at least two reasons.

Firstly they are unlikely to have the means to take electronic payment

Second, and more importantly, merchants get charged a percentage of the transaction.  These fees can be quite high to them for *premium* cards like travel and gold cards; three, four or even five percent of the value of the transaction.

This is sometimes why you see *cash discounted* pricing.

Comment: Do the amount of rewards of card really make a difference in how much the merchant is charged? That doesn't seem right, at least from my experience with ecommerce

Comment: @Sam Yes, interchange rates vary based on the card type. See, for example, [this list of Visa interchange rates](https://www.helcim.com/us/visa-interchange-rates/). Most of the big eCommerce payment platforms - Stripe, PayPal, etc. - just charge a high-ish rate across the board that lets them make enough profit on the average mix of cards their customers see.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. The [US Mint](http://catalog.usmint.gov/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10001&identifier=8100) has a deal where you can buy dollar coins for face value, free shipping and can charge them to your card. They come in small boxes of 10 x $25 rolls of coins. I'm sure your landlord will be happy to accept cash for the rent.

Upon further reflection you spelled it "cheque" which means these coins are not legal tender for you. You might want to add your country to the tags.

Note: This 'deal' is no longer available. It was (mis)used to get points/miles on credit cards, and the coins deposited at the bank. There's now a premium to buy the coins on line.

Comment: Wow that sounds really cool. What is stopping someone from buying $25k of coins and depositing them right back into their bank account so that they can get the points off of their credit card? Unfortunately I'm in Canada so that won't work.

Comment: There's a limit of $500 per order. I don't know if they'd catch on after a second or third order. No problem. I like Canada. In fact I hope you win tomorrow night, how's that?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Aside: Is that sweet shipping deal for dollar coins from the Mint likely to help the coin circulate?  I have yet to be offered a U.S. dollar coin as change when I'm travelling south. :-)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer +1 your comment for the hockey reference :-D

Comment: The intention of the mint is this should help them circulate. They ask not to deposit the rolled coins at the bank.

Comment: Joe, you've done this before? How do they ship them? USPS and leave them on my doorstep in a box marked US MINT? I want to buy some, but am a little nervous about $250 sitting on my front porch.

Comment: http://consumerist.com/2011/06/man-who-paid-25-bill-in-pennies-is-proud.html  I know your idea isn't pennies, but would a landlord really want coins?

Comment: Their is also a time limit of 10 days before the orders can be repeated.   Still it's a pretty cool program, and it does save us money compared to dollar bills which have such a short life compared to the coins.   Would save a lot if we could just break people from the bills and get them using coins instead for anything less than $5

Comment: Sean - I've not done it. I've grabbed some rolls at the bank, they're great to have in the car to pay tolls, and when going to the city, on a windy day dropping dollar bills into a homeless guy's hat or musician's case gets tough. I've ordered other Mint items, and yes, they came by US mail.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Which coins are at face value? The closest I see are $25o in coins for $275.95

Comment: This Q&A is over 5 years old. Things have changed, this deal is no longer available.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I got all excited thinking they'd brought it back.  I learned about it only a few months after they discontinued it back in the day.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned, it's largely up to the landlord. I'm in Texas, USA, and my landlord's payment service permits it, but they charge an exorbitant fee of 22%  plus 0.50 in order to do so. My rent is $895/month. If I chose to use a credit card, I pay $1092.40.

The miles aren't worth that kind of money.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is  to find out whether your landlord  will accept credit card payments. 
If yes, then I recommend you to try the easiest method first. Pay rent though a rent payment service. 
So, you need to log in with rental service and then chose the credit card using which you would like to pay rent and schedule your rent payments.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this question is probably way out of time, there might be another option.

If your landlord accepts Paypal payments, you can link your credit card to your Paypal account and use that to pay.

Answer (score 0):

A cheaper alternative might be automatic withdrawal/deposit. You may be able to negotiate a cheaper rate because then they will instantly receive the rent without any delay.